# Algebraic errors while using a keras model to make predictions (model.predict())

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to make predictions with the command model.predict() after modelling an ANN with keras and tensorflow, but I'm failling every time. 
It returns me the error: 'ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (31,) but got array with shape (1,)'.
I can't understand the bugg. My dataset is composed by 31 inputs, 45 targets and 10 samples. After I standardize them, I divided my dataset into 6 samples for training, 2 for validation and 2 for testing. Then I run the model. The MSE are promissing, but as I just have a few samples I really need to try it for predictions, actually I need the model to make predictions in first hand. So I have loaded another cvs file with 31 columns and 4 rows (as I want to make 4 different predictions). I have already standardize these data by using the mean and std of each feature of my original dataset.

My code for importing and preprocessing my original dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
data=np.loadtxt('dataset_mass.csv',delimiter=',')
unscaled_inputs=data[:,0:31]
unscaled_targets=data[:,38:83]
unscaled_inputs
scaled_inputs = preprocessing.scale(unscaled_inputs)
scaled_targets=preprocessing.scale(unscaled_targets)

samples_count=scaled_inputs.shape[0]
train_samples_count=int(0.6*samples_count)
validation_samples_count=int(0.2*samples_count)
test_samples_count=samples_count-train_samples_count-validation_samples_count

train_inputs=scaled_inputs[:train_samples_count]
train_targets=scaled_targets[:train_samples_count]

validation_inputs=scaled_inputs[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]
validation_targets=scaled_targets[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]

test_inputs=scaled_inputs[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]
test_targets=scaled_targets[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]

np.savez('coal_data_mass_train', inputs=train_inputs, targets=train_targets)
np.savez('coal_data_mass_validation', inputs=validation_inputs, targets=validation_targets)
```

My code for runnig the model, loading the input data for predicting and predicting:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

npz=np.load('coal_data_mass_train.npz')
train_inputs = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float)
train_targets = npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

npz = np.load('coal_data_mass_validation.npz')
validation_inputs, validation_targets = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float), npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

npz = np.load('coal_data_mass_test.npz')
test_inputs, test_targets = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float), npz['targets'].astype(np.int)
    np.savez('coal_data_mass_test', inputs=test_inputs, targets=test_targets)
input_size = 31
output_size = 45
hidden_layer_size = 3
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size,input_shape=(31,), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear') 
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['MeanAbsoluteError','mse'])

batch_size = 10
max_epochs = 20
callback=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)
model.fit(train_inputs, 
          train_targets, 
          batch_size=10, 
          epochs=max_epochs, 
          verbose=2,
          callbacks=[callback],
          validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets)
          )
test_loss= model.evaluate(test_inputs, test_targets)
OUT:
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/sample - loss: 0.7663 - mean_absolute_error: 0.7663 - mean_squared_error: 0.8220

input_data=np.loadtxt('inputs_data.csv',delimiter=',')
first_x=input_data[0,:]
first_y=model.predict(first_x)
print(first_y.shape)
OUT:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a75ab89125e1> in <module>
      1 st_x=in_data[0,:]
----> 2 first_y=model.predict(st_x)
      3 print(first_y.shape)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1058     # generate symbolic tensors).
   1059     x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(
-> 1060         x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
   1061 
   1062     if self.run_eagerly:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2649           feed_input_shapes,
   2650           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
-> 2651           exception_prefix='input')
   2652 
   2653     if y is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    383                              ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    384                              str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 385                              str(data_shape))
    386   return data
    387 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have shape (31,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Ive already tried to transpose the input_data matrix, I select the first column instead of the first row, but the error is the same.
Any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Comment: try to expand the batch dimension model.predict(first_x[None,:])

Comment: The neural network expected input with 31 columns, but got input with 1 column. Just print the shape throughout your preprocessing steps until you find the moment where the array supposed to be 31 columns have 1 column

Comment: check the shape of train_inputs. 
it have to match with first layer's input shape

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it worked!! thank you!!

Comment: @NicolasGervais thank you!

Comment: @VivekAnanthan thank you too!